# New window by clicking button?

Tags: java, swing

How to open a new window by clicking the button, and how do I move the button between the center en north.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class main {

    private JFrame f;
    private JPanel p;
    private JButton b1;


    public main()
    {
        gui();
    }

    public void gui() {

        f = new JFrame("creativity tuts");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(350,550);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        p = new JPanel();
        p.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        b1 = new JButton("Create Contact");

        p.add(b1);
        f.add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new main();  

    } 
}
```

Comment: if you can improve my code feel free to do so, I just started coding.

Comment: Hi Javamar, this is too broad as you're just asking someone to do your work. You need to provide an attempt at least. Read about [swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) in the java docs. Look up `ActionListener` too. Good luck.

Comment: For the first thing you should take a look at the [name conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). For the button you should take a look at the `ActionListener` this is what you need to get when the button is clicked

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: Please read about java naming convents. And use real names. There is ZERO point in using single chars as variable names.

Comment: `I just started coding.` - Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. `by clicking the button` - try the section on "How to Use Buttons". - Not sure exactly what you are asking but read the section on "Using Layout Managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("New Window");
 b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           newFrame.pack();
           newFrame.setVisible(true);
     }
 });
```

Dont forget name variables as a real not single letter, otherwise it will be hell to manage it